# Spring websocket/broker fail over

Tags: spring, websocket, activemq-classic, spring-websocket, failover

I have the following design:

- Machine1

  - WebsocketApp
  - ActiveMQ broker
- Machine2

  - WebsocketApp
  - ActiveMQ broker
- Machine3

  - WebsocketApp
  - ActiveMQ broker
- Machine4

  - WebsocketApp
  - ActiveMQ broker

The clients will use STOMP over WebSockets through an F5 load-balancer to connect to the ActiveMQ brokers. They can land on any machines based on the load factor.

For fail over scenarios how do we share the web socket sessions between ActiveMQ. Otherwise if the broker goes down all the sessions that it is holding will go down.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Some formatting issue. Three machines, each has websocket spring app and a broker. Websocket app will interact with the broker through spring broker connection configuration. Client will interact with broker through F5. Did I answer the question ? How to make the Broker fail safe. In case one of the broker node goes down, how the active sessions of a broker will be retained.

Comment: What is a "spring broker connection configuration"? Also, will the clients going through the F5 load-balancer be using WebSockets? What messaging protocol will they be using? STOMP? AMQP?

Comment: spring broker am planning to use stomp. yes client will be using F5 load balance for websockets. STOMP.

Comment: So both the WebSocketApp and the clients coming through the F5 will be using STOMP over WebSockets? Sorry to keep asking, but it's just not clear so far.

Comment: no problem. You are helping in the forum, unless you have more details, you cannot help. May be my usage of terms in STOMP is not right. WebsocketApp will connect to ActiveMQ broker (not sure if it is STOMP or any other way). Client will connect to Active MQ Broker using F5. The URL will start with wss:// and if we will use activemq.js to connect there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STOMP is a very *simple* protocol. It has no support for fail-over.

If the broker to which a STOMP client is connected goes down in your environment then that client's connection will go down and all the messages on that broker will be unavailable until the broker comes back up. The client will need to reconnect to another broker via the F5 URL.

STOMP connections are not like HTTP. They are stateful. Client "session" data is not shared among brokers. If a client's broker goes down then it cannot simply carry on as if nothing happened like is often possible for HTTP use-cases.

Comment: Thanks. I have a distributed coherence cache. Eliminating all these, will I be able to use just spring websocket app and coherence cache. I will store the session information in coherence cache. If the websocket app goes, client will reconnect with original subscription id and we can restore the session information. This way I dont need a broker setup and it does not help much in fail over.